# Issues with exporting Neo4j 3.2.2 Graph to Gephi 0.9.1

Tags: neo4j, gephi, graphml, neo4j-plugin

As there is no Neo4j plugin for Grephi 0.9.1 I tried to export my Neo4j graph as an .graphml file. I created an empty .graphml file in Grephi and used the procedure:

```
call apoc.export.graphml.all('file:C:/test.graphml',{})
```

However I recieve:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.export.graphml.all`: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:C:\test.graphml (Syntax of filename, directory or harddrive is wrong)
```

in the neo4j.conf file I added before:

```
apoc.export.file.enabled=true
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found helpful information here:

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/15397fjvyy/export-graphml

"import-graphml can read from an URL but as you can't write to an URL the export only supports normal path syntax"

so this worked for me:

```
call apoc.export.graphml.all('C:/test.graphml',{})
```